# Delay in php sleep functions their selves?

Tags: php, pthreads, sleep, usleep

I have a PHP program that should sleep for some time to make it tick 100 times per 1 second in it's process while loop.
But when I want to calculate the time lapsed for a 100 tick cycle I get more than 1 second. Is this a problem from my code or this is a known problem of PHP?

Note: I am using pthreads for my program and the process is running on a Thread that is made by the main Thread.

I am currently using function time_sleep_until() but I also tried usleep() and had the same problem. It does not matter which one is used I just want a precise tps for my program and I am struggling too much with this.

My code:

```php
<?php

class Program extends \Thread {

    private const TPS = 100;

    private int $tickCounter = 0;

    public function run(){
        while(true){
            $start = microtime(true);

            if(($this->tickCounter % self::TPS) === 0){
                $time = round(microtime(true) - $this->tickTime, 3);
                echo "Time per 1 cycle: " . $time . PHP_EOL;
                $this->tickTime = microtime(true);
            }

            // Process some jobs

            $this->tickCounter++;

            $until = microtime(true) - $start;
            if($until < (1 / self::TPS)){
                @time_sleep_until((microtime(true) + (1 / self::TPS)) - $until);
            }
        }
    }
}

$program = new Program();
$program->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_NONE);
```

This will take around 1.56sec to cycle 100 ticks while I am not even processing anything as a job. But expected to take 1sec or at least as precise as it can.
Also when I put 1 instead of 100 for `Program::TPS` lapsed time gets 1sec or very close to 1sec.

Comment: I find your code _unnecessarily_ cryptic. Especially the line `@time_sleep_until((microtime(true) + (1 / self::TPS)) - $until);` is difficult to comprehend. If I replace `$until` by what was assigned to it I think I get: `@time_sleep_until($start + (1 / self::TPS));` which looks like a proper bug to me. I have my doubts about the rest as well. Can you explain how your code works?

Comment: I also tried your code but it takes the same 1.56sec but thanks for the better code :D. Actually I am making a server software that handles messages received from a UDP socket(RakNet protocol to be exact) and this is the main process of sending and receiving jobs and it should be 100 times run per 1sec in my case.

Comment: A job can easily take longer than 10 ms, even if it normally executes in less than that, or is executed asynchronously. Why? Because a server does more than just run your PHP code. A lot more. Any of these other processes can slow the execution of your jobs down. Or what if your process needs to access a spinning drive? This can take very long. The best approach is to never assume that something will execute in a certain time, which is what your code does.

Comment: The proper way to do what you want is to get the time once before the endless loop. Then every time you process a job you add 10 ms to that time. Call this the "computed time". Note that a job can easily take longer than 10 ms, so in that case you need to add another 10 ms, and another, until the computed time has caught up to, and exceeded, the real time. Then you sleep until the computed time. This all means that the maximum number of jobs you can handle in 1 second is a 100, but it can be fewer when there are jobs that take more than 10 ms.